# smart GPS using - only if app is in foreground

Tags: android, gps

I would like to use GPS in my application but in some specific way. I want to use it only when the user does something with the app, but when the app goes to sleep then the GPS should stop doing things. I wonder how to manage this in way in which I wouldn't have to manage gps in all activities but only in one class or something similar.

Comment: Please help us help you; if none of our answers are worthy of being accepted, letting us know why that's the case improves SO for everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the GPS is used only in one Activity
Turn off the GPS when the Activity's `onPause()` method is called.

```
@Override
protected void onPause()
{
//turn of GPS code here
super.onPause();
}
```

If your GPS is running in service you will have to have the service know if your app is running or not, what you can do is make a static boolean in the Service and every time any Activity's `onResume()` method is called, set the Service's boolean to true. Every time an Activity pauses, set the boolean to false.

Comment: I need this in many Activities. Well... It's some solution but i wonder if is there a posibility to do sth like onPause in class extends Application or sth. That would be cool IMO.

Comment: Well the application being "paused" is too broad. For example a Broadcast Receiver continues to work as long as the Activity that registered it is in memory. In your case a service is most likely the easiest and cleanest solution.

Comment: Sure, sorry. Your answer with advice to use service is good and it works ; )